# Difference between render with locals and without locals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to know the difference between

```
   render('shared/comment', comment: @comment)
```

and

```
   render('shared/comment', locals: {comment: @comment})
```

For me,  sometimes the first method can work , but sometimes the second method ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have doubts about the parameters of a Rails method, I recommend looking at [apidock](http://apidock.com/) because it allows you to switch the rails version, which can be handy if things changed over time.

You can see that there is a render method on [ActionController:Base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) and the favorite one I think is from [ActiveView:Template](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Template/render)

The `ActionController` method has the following signature:

```
render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block)
```

And the `ActionView` has the following one:

```
render(view, locals, buffer=nil, &block)
```

So basically you need to use `locals:` when you are calling the deprecated method from `ActionController`, and don't need to pass it when using the `ActionView` one.